# cairo-dock (fallback) won't run at start-up (ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: 16.04, startup, autostart, cairo-dock

I worked through all the commands in macbuntu so that I could get the el-capitan desktop, and the final step, using Cairo-dock to put the menu on the bottom is giving me fits...

I run cairo-dock (fallback) and click to NOT use openGL (makes stuff jumpy and unattractive), and right click the cairo-dock and click where it says run at startup.  The icon is a grey, and doesn't change colors.

I've tried a buncha times, and it just won't work.  I even opened the start-up menu and added cairo-dock to startup, and still nothing.

Could it be that 16.04 and my version of Cairo-dock just aren't making the love connection yet?  Far as I know, I have all the newest updates.  Also, I've searched and ran several suggested lines in Terminal, all with no luck.

It's not the end of the world, but call me crazy, I want the El Capitan look without having to go to Super and opening up the cairo-dock thattaway...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and fixed it by creating a new cairo-dock-starter item in startup.

I named it **Cairo Dock** and the command for the startup is

```
cairo-dock -c
```

you can find the description here:

http://glx-dock.org/ww_page.php?p=Execute%20cairo-dock%20at%20startup&lang=en

I hope it will work in your system as well! :)

Comment: please provide the steps here in more detail :)

Comment: @Zanna You know, there was a button to switch the language to English on the linked site...